# Can't delete field from firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can't delete field from firestore

```
else if(starPosition == 0){
   Map<String, Object> deleteRating = new HashMap<>();
   deleteRating.put(inititalRating + "_star", documentSnapshot.getLong(inititalRating + "_star") - 1);
   deleteRating.put("average_rating", String.valueOf(calculateAverageRating(starPosition-inititalRating,true)));
   deleteRating.put("total_ratings", documentSnapshot.getLong("total_ratings") - 1);

   firebaseFirestore.collection("PRODUCTS").document(productID)
           .update(deleteRating).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
       @Override
       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
           if (task.isSuccessful()) {
               Map<String, Object> ratingUpdate = new HashMap<>();
               ratingUpdate.put("list_size", DBqueries.myRatedIds.size() - 1);
               ratingUpdate.put("product_ID_" + DBqueries.myRatedIds.size(), FieldValue.delete());
               ratingUpdate.put("rating_" + DBqueries.myRatedIds.size(), FieldValue.delete());

               firebaseFirestore.collection("USERS").document(currentUser.getUid()).collection("USER_DATA").document("MY_RATINGS")
                       .update(ratingUpdate).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                   }
               });


           }
       }
   });    

}
```

There field is not deleted I used here FieldValue.delete()

[image: Screenshot firestore fielsd]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counter is off by one. You run:

```
   Map<String, Object> ratingUpdate = new HashMap<>();
   ratingUpdate.put("list_size", DBqueries.myRatedIds.size() - 1);
   ratingUpdate.put("product_ID_" + DBqueries.myRatedIds.size(), FieldValue.delete());
   ratingUpdate.put("rating_" + DBqueries.myRatedIds.size(), FieldValue.delete());

   firebaseFirestore.collection("USERS").document(currentUser.getUid()).collection("USER_DATA").document("MY_RATINGS")
```

Since the screenshot shows `list_size` as 0, that means `DBqueries.myRatedIds.size()` is 1. So you're deleting the `product_ID_1` and `rating_1` fields, which are indeed not/no longer present in the document.

If you want to delete the `0` index fields, you'll need to use `DBqueries.myRatedIds.size() - 1` there too.